# How to resolve this repository error ? Nothing seems to work

Tags: java, android, bolts-framework

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-quickstart-example-master-master'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.5.0.

Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- http://maven.google.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom

Required by:
project : > com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3

> Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.5.0.

Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- http://maven.google.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-tasks/1.5.0/bolts-tasks-1.5.0.pom

Required by:
project : > com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.5.0

> Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.5.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-applinks/1.5.0/bolts-applinks-1.5.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-applinks/1.5.0/bolts-applinks-1.5.0.pom
> - http://maven.google.com/com/parse/bolts/bolts-applinks/1.5.0/bolts-applinks-1.5.0.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-applinks/1.5.0/bolts-applinks-1.5.0.pom
> Required by:
> project : > com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.5.0

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Hard to say without seeing you maven or gradle file. The error itself says that you (or some library you use) has declared that it's dependent of bolt-tasks-1.5.0, but according to Maven Central their newest distributed version is 1.4.0. Their Github says that 1.5.0 has been released, but it's obviosuly not distributed to central

Comment: ok thanks. I am really new to android studio. I guess I need to make it 1.4.0